# Redshift list all schemanames, tablenames and columnnames

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, information-schema

I was trying to join on `information_schema.columns` but found out that it cannot be done, and that `pg_table_def` is the equivalent.

But it has the problem of displaying only the schemas that are present in the `search_path`, how can I get an `information_schema.columns` equivalent from `pg_table_def`

Or set the `search_path` to search everywhere?

Comment: I need to list all the schemas, respective tables and columns for the respective tables

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you are using Amazon Redshift, that information can be derived from `svv_column` view.

e.g. query

```
SELECT * FROM svv_columns;
```

Ref: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_SVV_COLUMNS.html

This is not affected by `search_path` and permissions for user running it and is visible to all users.

Answer (score 1):

**Step 1: get all the schemas**

```
select nspname FROM pg_namespace
where nspname not like 'pg_%' --to execlude pg schemas unless you need them
and nspname not in (select schemaname from svv_external_schemas); -- to execlude external schemas because you cannot add them to search path
```

**step2: make them into a comma separated list**

take the result of the query above and convert to schema1,schema2,schema3,schema4...schema(n)

**step3: set your search path**

```
SET search_path to schema1,schema2,schema3,schema4...schema(n)
```

**step 4 pg_table_def**

SELECT * FROM pg_table_def

Answer (score 0):

Posting this as an automated solution via SQL and jinja2 templating, this is run in DBT

```sql
{% macro populate_schema_catalog(target_schema_name, target_table_name) %}
{%- set fetch_all_schemas -%}
    SELECT
        nspname
    FROM
        pg_namespace
    WHERE
        nspname NOT LIKE 'pg_%'
        AND nspname NOT IN (
            SELECT
                schemaname
            FROM
                svv_external_schemas
        );
{%- endset -%}

{%- set all_schemas = run_query(fetch_all_schemas).rows.values() -%}
{%- set schema_list = [] -%}

-- The schema list now contains all the schemas as such ['"meta"', '"adhoc_dbt"', ...]
{% for schema in all_schemas %}
    {%- do schema_list.append('"{}"'.format(schema[0]))-%}
{% endfor %}

-- Set the search_path
{%- set set_search_path -%}
    SET search_path TO {{ ', '.join(schema_list) }};
{%- endset -%}

{%- do run_query(set_search_path) -%}

{%- set query_pg_table_def -%}
    SELECT
        *
    FROM
        pg_table_def
{%- endset -%}

{%- set all_information = run_query(query_pg_table_def).rows.values() -%}

{% for row in all_information %}
{{ log(row) }}
{% endfor %}

{% endmacro %}
```